# How to configure multiple address in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am using woocommerce in my e commerce website. I want my customers to be able to save multiple shipping and billing addresses. The addresses can be viewed and edited from my account page. In the checkout page they should be able to select one of the addresses they have already saved.

I have googled a lot and found absolutely nothing but a plugin which does not serve the purpose. I went through the woocommerce documentation but not able to figure out. I am actually overwhelmed by it and feeling lost.

Please help me guys and at least point me somewhere. This is a very common feature in a lots of website nowadays and i am sure it can be done.

Comment: I think you need to customize your woocommerce plugin as your requirement. Because mostly CMS just give one option for the address.

Comment: Thanks Rizwan for the response. I understand that, but i am unable to understand in which part i should change and write my custom code. The documentation states almost nothing. I need a starting point to jump off. can you please point me there.

Answer (score 2):

In default, as you know WooCommerce only allow one billing & shipping address. But using custom code or plugins, you can achieve this feature in WooCommerce.

Writing code snippet is little difficult as per your question. But if I need the tweaks you mentioned, my approach will be given below.

1. Edit Checkout form with option to insert new address / select a address from saved list.
2. Create option in My Account page to insert new address.
3. Save the new user data in user meta.

If you are looking for a plugin, I would like to suggest  [WooCommerce Multiple Addresses Pro plugin](https://www.themehigh.com/product/woocommerce-multiple-addresses-pro) which allows your customers to save multiple shipping and billing addresses to their My Account page.

Also the newly added addresses will be available in My Account page of the online store, from where the shopper can add, edit or remove addresses.

Moreover, the shopper can set the addresses as default, billing and shipping separately.I think this plugin will be best solution for your demands.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use this plugin: [Woocommerce Multiple Addresses](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-multiple-addresses/)

Comment: It works fine in my projects. If you have any problems you could contact developer on plugin's support forum http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce-multiple-addresses

Comment: I already did. They said they are yet to include those features. Did you tweak this plugin ? How do you view all the addresses that are saved ? Are you able to display all the addresses in the checkout page ?  Can you plz give me the link where you implemented this. I need to show all saved addresses in the myaccount page and in the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Shipping Multiple Addresses plugin, add [woocommerce_select_multiple_addresses] to the checkout page.

Answer (score -3):

It is working perfect.First i'm going to buy http://www.woothemes.com/products/shipping-multiple-addresses/ this plugging but this plugging save my money.